# SQL Query: "Write one SQL Query to calculate the maximum salaries for employees by Job Classification

Tags: sql, sql-server

The task is to "Write one SQL Query to calculate the maximum salaries for employees by Job Classification. (Output shows Alias).

There were two tables created, the Employee and Job_Title. The Employee table consists of the Salary while the the Job_Title table consists of the Job Classification such as 'Manager'.

The current code I have shown, the employee who has the max salary in that classification, however, the Alias is not showing. It just displays all of the information for that Employee.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Employee
WHERE   Salary IN (
        SELECT  MAX(Salary) AS 'Maximum_Salary_Class'
        FROM    Employee
        WHERE   JobID IN ( SELECT   JobID
                           FROM     Job_Title_Table_
                           WHERE    Job_Classification = 'Manager' ) );
```

Comment: Which "alias"? I don't get what you want to show.

Comment: Don't they teach joins no more?

Comment: @IvanStarostin There's only one alias here.

Comment: Please add table structure to your question.

Comment: This is a pretty simple `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `MAX` query, you should do some more research rather than looking to be spoon fed an answer.

Comment: Does your assignment ask for the maximum salary for a given job classification, or the maximum salary for each of the different job classifictations?

Comment: Tobb, it is a bit confusing, however, I may just go with the Maximum for each of the different classifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select t.Job_Classification, max(e.salary) as 'Maximum_Salary_Class' 
from Employee e join Job_Title_Table_ t on e.JobID = t.JobId
group by t.Job_Classification;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
;with cte as
(
select E.*,J.Job_Classification,Dense_RAnk() over(partition by J.Job_Classification order by E.Salary) as DenseRank
from Employee E
inner join Job_Title J on E.JobID = J.JobID
)
select * from cte
where DenseRank = 1
```

I tried to understand your purpose.
Let me know if I didnt get correctly.

Comment: Todd.. what have you changed  ?

Comment: Just edit your post without saving to see how it's done.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to get this

```
SELECT E.*,Job_Classification 
FROM Employee
,(
  SELECT J.JobID,J.Job_Classification,MAX(Salary) AS 'Maximum_Salary_Class'
  FROM Employee AS E
  ,Job_Title_Table_ AS J
  WHERE E.JobID = J.JobID
  AND Job_Classification = 'Manager'
  GROUP BY J.JobID,J.Job_Classification
) AS EJ
WHERE E.JobID = EJ.JobID
AND Salary = Maximum_Salary_Class
```